# Java fasterxml.jackson deserialize LocalDateTime wrongTokenException

Tags: java, json, spring, deserialization, fasterxml

- Java 1.8
- Spring Boot 1.5.8
- faster.xml.jackson (`jackson-module-parameter-names`, `jackson-datatype-jdk8`, `jackson-datatype-jsr310`) 2.9.2

I have a object with a timestamp.

```
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
private LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

The `LocalDateTime` stamp I need to deserialize is:

```
{ 
   "year":2017,
   "month":"OCTOBER",
   "dayOfMonth":27,
   "dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY",
   "dayOfYear":300,
   "monthValue":10,
   "nano":460000000,
   "hour":4,
   "minute":47,
   "second":29,
   "chronology":{  
      "calendarType":"iso8601",
      "id":"ISO"
   }
}
```

I try to deserialize the object with:

```
MyObject myObject=
         new ObjectMapper()
             .findAndRegisterModules()
             .treeToValue(jsonPayload, MyObject.class);
```

The application freezes at this call and if I interrupt the call I get the following error message:

```
Error while stopping the container:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException;
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java:138) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.2.jar!/:2.9.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateTimeDeserializer.deserialize(LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java:39) ~[jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.2.jar!/:2.9.2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:504) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:276) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:2612) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/:2.8.10]
```

**UPDATE'S:**

The whole JSON is:

```
{"valid":true,"version":"0.0.1",
"timestamp":{"year":2017,"month":"OCTOBER","dayOfMonth":27,"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","dayOfYear":300,"monthValue":10,"nano":460000000,"hour":4,"minute":47,"second":29,"chronology":{"calendarType":"iso8601","id":"ISO"}},
"tenant":"stackoverflow","uid":"10fa132f-2c92-4fa5-bcc2-ee6023281503"})
```

Serialized with:

```
String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(messageIndex);
```

The object attributes:

```
@JsonProperty("version")
private String version;

@JsonProperty("timestamp")
private LocalDateTime timestamp;

@JsonProperty("tenant")
private String tenant;

@JsonProperty("dataSampleUid")
private UUID uid;

private boolean isValid;
```

The `LocalDateTime` is set with:

```
LocalDateTime.now()
```

Comment: Any reason to use treeToValue? Why dont you use jsonMapper.readValue(object, class)  ?

Comment: With a JsonNode you can validate the schema. I tried it with readValue, no change. The problem is, that the deserializer got problems with the LocalDateTime, see row 3 and 4 of the Error snippet.

Comment: Im just curious, can you revert your jackson dependencies, especially the jackson-datatype-jsr310 from version 2.9.2 to an earlier version, e.g. 2.8.10?

Comment: I wrote a little test with one POJO containing one timestamp. The difference to your JSOn is when I serialize it the JSOn looks like {"timestamp":[2017,10,27,8,22]} instead of yours looking quite too verbose. Maybe you only have to check your serializing side and adjust it a bit.

Comment: Your json representation of the LocalDateTime is not how JavaTimeModule handle it. The serialized LocalDateTime look like a default serialization of an object (all accessible field of the object).  Could you show us how you serialized it ? However when you are deserializing it you register the JavaTimeModule and therefore expect an array (like @mrkernelpanic said)

Comment: @JEY updated post with serialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When serializing you didn't register any module especially the JavaTimeModule therefore LocalDateTime are going to be serialized just like any other object (printing all their accessible fields). However in the deserialization part you registered this module and they expect a specific format for the LocalDateTime ([by default an array](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime#summary)).

If you want this to work just update the serialization part:

```
String jsonString = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules().writeValueAsString(messageIndex);
```

You should reuse the same object mapper through your application same is true for reader. Both because of thread-safety and because instances are relatively light-weight.

Run this and you will see that it's working properly and you will see the differences in LocalDateTime serialized value.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
MyObject data = new MyObject();
data.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
System.out.println(result);
JsonNode tree = mapper.reader().readTree(result);
mapper.treeToValue(tree, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: Makes no change

Comment: I added a quick sample run it you'll see.

Comment: You're right, I made complete cleanup before the build and now everything works! Thank's alot!